# How to update the graphics driver in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, gpu-driver

I have an Nvidia G84 [GeForce 8600 GT] graphics processor. Does anyone know how to update the graphics driver in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: It is better NOT to do anything with drivers for this old hardware if it works more or less OK. New drivers do not support it well.

Answer (score 0):

In the Dash home ,type Additional Drivers ,  it opens softwares and updates windows , now select additional drivers tab , it shows up the drivers you can update to click update and your drivers get updated